# Chartboost interstitial not showing when test mode is disabled in android

Tags: chartboost

```
this.mChartboost = Chartboost.sharedChartboost();
String appId = "XYZ";
String appSignature = "ABC";

this.mChartboost.onCreate(this,appId,appSignature, null);
this.mChartboost.startSession();

this.mChartboost.showInterstitial();
```

Test ads are seen using this code..but when i disable the test mode no ads are seen at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having the same issue here. After contacting the Chartboost support team, they gave me the following answer. I have not tried to do the following steps yet, but I hope this can help you in some way.

***Chartboost response:***
In general, what you're describing happens when no more of the interstitials available at the time you're testing in the network satisfy the conditions you and the advertisers set in your campaigns. Advertisers choose conditions/parameters they would like to target so that they can acquire specific users. These conditions include filtered apps/publishers/age ratings/genres, country/device/OS targeting and more. Assuming that the integration was successful (you're able to see a green test interstitial from us), chances are your location (country) may be the limiting factor. There's a few things we can try from here:

- Double check that your app orientation has been properly selected in the app settings in the Chartboost dashboard.
- Create a Cross Promotion campaign in your dashboard to always see your own custom creative. Cross Promotion campaigns are used as a way to promote one of more of your Apps amongst each other. There's more information on Cross Promotion campaigns [here](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/crosspromos). Below are the steps I recommend taking:

  1. Create a new App on your dashboard, call it "Test App". Put in a redirect URL for it.
  2. Upload creatives for "Test App". There's more information about creatives located at https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/creatives
  3. Now that creatives have been uploaded, you can navigate to Campaigns -> Add Campaign -> Cross Promotion
  4. Here, you'll want to choose to advertise "Test App" inside of the App you're trying to see interstitials in.
  5. Scroll down and choose to show interstitials "Every time" and stop showing once "user installs the app"

The key here is to never integrate the Chartboost App ID/Signature belonging to "Test App". So long as "Test App" is not integrated, you will always see the Cross Promotion campaign. Please be sure to delete or turn off the Cross Promotion campaign before you go live!

- Use a VPN/proxy to have your IP address change. We target users by reverse looking up the device IP address. If you can change your IP address for testing purposes, you may be able to see more interstitials.

Answer (score 0):

In case videos are not available in your region try using proxy to US. I used TunnelBear (available on play-store), and I was sucessfully able to load ads in US region.